# No converter found capable of converting from type org.bson.types.ObjectId to type org.bson.types.ObjectId

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, jboss7.x, objectid

I'm having some trouble to sort out a issue that came out yesterday in my web application.

So here's the scenario :

I have web application running on Jboos 7 , that often consults a mongodb database. Every document on this database has an ObjectId as _id . The converters and id serializers and deserializers are in an *api* that my web application includes in its *manifestEntries* of the pom.xml .

Now every time I try to get a Document from mongodb I get the following exception

```
 org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type org.bson.types.ObjectId to type org.bson.types.ObjectId
```

For me, this would make some sense if the objects where actually different but they are the same. I'm not posting any code because I believe this might be or a Jboss thing or a Maven issue . Can anyone give some lights over this problem ?

Thank you,
Pedro

Comment: Looks like the classes are on differend class loader. make sure that the jar containing `org.bson.types.ObjectId` is only available once in the classloader hierarchy.

Comment: Hi Jens,  how can I check that ? I checked target\SERVICE\WEB-INF\lib folder after package and mongo-java-driver (witch contains the `org.bson.ObjectId` ) appears only once. Thank you

Comment: And in your lib directories of the jboss is there also the `jar`?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the field id type to BigInteger and now it works.